# Salesforce case create notification to my application

Tags: salesforce

Is there a way for salesforce.com api to push a notification to my application or into my network when a case record is created for my enterprise SF account? I wish to receive some sort of notification (via some kind of publication/subscription model maybe) to my network server so that my custom application can respond to that.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Workflow rule with Email Alert to send a notification: Your Name | Setup | Create | Workflow & Approvals | Workflow Rules

You could also create a trigger (on insert Case) to do an Apex Callout to directly interact with your application/service, if SOAP/REST is supported. Apex Web Services and Callouts doc could be found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts